# C# Httpclient singleton with same authentication header on multiple client/user

Tags: c#, azure-functions, singleton, dotnet-httpclient

I have an Azure function that calls API and I made my HttpClient as a singleton in the startup Dependency Injection so I can call it on my contractor. My code below calls two API with the same Authentication header.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        
        public void test(string OAuthToken)
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OAuthToken);

            // 1st API
            string firstApi = $"https://GetSometthingFirst.com/processes?api-version=5.0";
            var GetFirst = _httpClient.GetAsync(firstApi).Result;

             // add delay 5 secs
             Thread.Sleep(5000);
    

            // 2nd API
            string secondApi = $"https://GetSometthingSecond.com/processes?api-version=5.0";
            var content = new StringContent(GetFirst.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = _httpClient.PostAsync(secondApi, content).Result;
        }

}
```

In the code above I have two API calls which use the same `DefaultRequestHeader`. Since it's a singleton the function can call by multiple user with different `OAthToken` as the parameter and share the same instance of HttpClient. Should I need to refresh the Default header like this so the other thread wont be affected?

```
public void test(string OAuthToken)
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OAuthToken);

            // 1st API
            string firstApi = $"https://GetSometthingFirst.com/processes?api-version=5.0";
            var GetFirst = _httpClient.GetAsync(firstApi).Result;

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OAuthToken);

             // add delay 5 secs
             Thread.Sleep(5000)

            // 2nd API
            string secondApi = $"https://GetSometthingSecond.com/processes?api-version=5.0";
            var content = new StringContent(GetFirst.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = _httpClient.PostAsync(secondApi, content).Result;
        }
```

Comment: `OAuthToken` is same for all requests or it changes ?

Comment: yup it change for every users or client.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation suggests you [use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) . It makes the management of HttpClient instances easier.